# Why there is a difference in time for x axis if I zoom into the Plot

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I am working with python pandas and reading a csv file with several columns. Also included in the files are several time columns. I drop them out and select only one column as time column. I define this column as index and also set it as time.

Next is: I would like to plot a specific column to get a first impression.
In the data I see that the values for this column drop from 600 to zero at 10:42, see image:

[image]

If I plot the column, I get the following image

[image]

However, if I zoom in, I get the following

[image]

As it can be seen there is a huge difference in the images. Something seems to go wrong.

I have the following code

```
data_304=pd.read_csv(r"data.csv",sep=";")
data_304=data_304.drop(["columns_to_drop"],axis=1)
data_304['date']=pd.to_datetime(data_304['date'])
data_304=data_304.set_index('piovan_1_dosing_creation_date')
data_304.index=data_304.index.map(lambda t: t.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M'))

data_304["piovan_1_dosing_batchvalue_value"].plot()
```

I assume that this might be due to the time zone, but I didnt find a proper way.
I would be very grateful if you could give me a tip :)

Comment: Interesting problem. But can you provide a [mcve], such that people have a chance to investigate?

Comment: *How* do you zoom in? With the matplotlib interactive zoom?

Comment: As far as I see it, there are no differences between the two plots, except for the horizontal scales, which is a result of your 'zooming in'.

Comment: Yes indeed I use matplotlib interactive zoom

Comment: There is the difference that the dip is at a different time..

Comment: The minimal code is the one I already postet. I just deleted the paths and columns which I don't need for the further analytics

Comment: The example is minimal, but not complete. Ask yourself: how can someone else reproduce the problem on his/her computer?

Comment: Oh, your index are strings. That explains it. That's more or less like asking where `"yesterday"` would be on the axis.

Comment: By applying pd.to_datatime I set it as time. The type of the column is the time specific type datetime[ns]. I will upload the data sheet and the entire code on Monday :)

Comment: @Importance: I think I understood your comment about string. I just had a quick look on the strftime() command and realized that my time is transformed into a string, which will probably lead to this issue

Answer (score 0):

first of all let me thank you for your help, I really appreciate it :)
@ImportanceOfBeingErnest: You were right. The issue with zoom in and zoom out is due to the fact that I converted my index which is type of **dtype='datetime64[ns]'** to string using the line

`data_304.index=data_304.index.map(lambda t: t.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M'))`

Since my index goes up to milliseconds but I am not interested in milliseconds rather than seconds I looked for a way to just show seconds. And the line mentioned abve using the strftime() was the solution I found. Unfortunately, I was not smart enough to check what happens in the background and couldn't find the answer to my problem described in the first mail.

After a bit searching and focussing I found the following information which helps me to set the milliseconds to zero and still keep the type **dtype='datetime64[ns]'**, which is done by

```
data_304.index=data_304.index.values.astype('<M8[m]')
```

Applying this to my data changes the index time appearance from

**2019-04-24 05:41:13.809000** to **2019-04-24 05:41:00**

As mentioned the type remains datetime64[ns]

Maybe this helps you guys if you want to keep type and truncate the index

Cheers  and thanks again :)